# Why do we use half of the risk in objective function of markowitz portfolio theory

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, markowitz

In some documents I have seen objective function of markowitz portfolio theory is as follows.

```
minimize 1/2 * w'Σw
where w is weights
Σ is covariance matrix
```

I could not understand where does 1/2 come from? Is it there for taking half of the risk because we only care about down-side deviation?

Thanks!

Comment: It is only a convention, you can minimize w'Σw if you want and get the same result. It is just that the derivative of w'Σw is 2Σw, so the 2 automatically cancels the 1/2 and you get a simpler expression when you take the Lagrangian. So the 1/2 is to make the theoreticians happy, makes no difference to the final result. (For a similar reason modern physicists define kinetic energy as $\frac{1}{2}m v^2$ even though Leibnitz initially used vis viva or $m v^2$. It looks better when you take the derivative)

Comment: @noob2 Thank you! Do you have any document for `derivative of w'Σw is 2Σw`? I would like to learn more about that.

Comment: Maybe this one https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~schmidtm/Courses/Notes/linearQuadraticGradients.pdf

Comment: The matrix cookbook is the reference of my choice http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/edoc/imm3274.pdf